# matching a preceding element text contain

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I'm writing a template, where if there is a processing instruction containing `main` after a `footnote` and no another `footnote` in between these two(`the processing instruction` and `current footnote`) I need a line to be added.

Below is my XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<body>
    <?xpp MAIN;2;0;0;0;45;0;0?>
    <?xpp foot;art10_ft7;suppress?>
    <?xpp FOOT;art10_ft7;1?>
    <footnote label="7" id="art10_ft7">
        <para>
                    text
          </para>
    </footnote>
    <?xpp foot;art10_ft8;suppress?>
    <?xpp FOOT;art10_ft8;1?>
    <footnote label="8" id="art10_ft8">
        <para>
                    text
          </para>
    </footnote>
    <?xpp foot;art10_ft9;suppress?>
    <?xpp FOOT;art10_ft9;1?>
    <footnote label="9" id="art10_ft9">
        <para>
                    text
          </para>
    </footnote>
    <?xpp MAIN;3;0;0;0;46;0;0?>
    <?xpp foot;art10_ft20;suppress?>
    <?xpp FOOT;art10_ft20;1?>
    <footnote label="20" id="art10_ft20">
        <para>text</para>
    </footnote>
    <?xpp foot;art10_ft20;suppress?>
    <?xpp FOOT;art10_ft20;1?>
    <footnote label="21" id="art10_ft20">
        <para>text</para>
    </footnote>
    <?xpp foot;art10_ft20;suppress?>
    <?xpp FOOT;art10_ft20;1?>
    <footnote label="22" id="art10_ft20">
        <para>text</para>
    </footnote>
    <?xpp MAIN;3;0;0;0;46;0;0?>
    <?xpp foot;art10_ft20;suppress?>
    <?xpp FOOT;art10_ft20;1?>
    <footnote label="23" id="art10_ft20">
        <para>text</para>
    </footnote>

</body>
```

And I'm trying with the below XSLT.

```
<xsl:template match="footnote" mode="footnote">
    <xsl:variable name="count" select="count(preceding::footnote)+1"/>
    <div class="tr_footnote">
        <div class="footnote">
            <sup>
                <a>
                    <xsl:attribute name="name"><xsl:text>ftn.</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$count"/></xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:text>#f</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$count"/></xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="class"><xsl:text>tr_ftn</xsl:text></xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@label"/>
                </a>
            </sup>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </div>
    </div>
   <!--Here I need the change-->
    <xsl:if test="following::processing-instruction('xpp')/text()[contains(.,'MAIN')][1][preceding::footnote[1]/@label=./@label]">
        <xsl:text>-------------------------</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Currently I'm getting the below output.

```
 <section class="tr_footnotes"><hr /><?pb label=''?>
      <div class="tr_footnote">
         <div class="footnote"><sup><a name="ftn.1" href="#f1" class="tr_ftn">7</a></sup>                   
            <para>text</para>               
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="tr_footnote">
         <div class="footnote"><sup><a name="ftn.2" href="#f2" class="tr_ftn">8</a></sup>                   
            <para>text</para>               
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="tr_footnote">
         <div class="footnote"><sup><a name="ftn.3" href="#f3" class="tr_ftn">9</a></sup>                   
            <para>text</para>               
         </div>
      </div><?pb label=''?>
      <div class="tr_footnote">
         <div class="footnote"><sup><a name="ftn.4" href="#f4" class="tr_ftn">20</a></sup>                  
            <para>text</para>               
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="tr_footnote">
         <div class="footnote"><sup><a name="ftn.5" href="#f5" class="tr_ftn">21</a></sup>                  
            <para>text</para>               
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="tr_footnote">
         <div class="footnote"><sup><a name="ftn.6" href="#f6" class="tr_ftn">22</a></sup>                  
            <para>text</para>               
         </div>
      </div><?pb label=''?>
      <div class="tr_footnote">
         <div class="footnote"><sup><a name="ftn.7" href="#f7" class="tr_ftn">23</a></sup>                  
            <para>text</para>               
         </div>
      </div>
   </section>
```

And my expected output is

```
<!DOCTYPE html
  PUBLIC "XSLT-compat">
<hmtl>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <title>New Version!</title>
   </head>
   <section class="tr_footnotes"><hr /><?pb label=''?>
      <div class="tr_footnote">
         <div class="footnote"><sup><a name="ftn.1" href="#f1" class="tr_ftn">7</a></sup>                   
            <para>text</para>               
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="tr_footnote">
         <div class="footnote"><sup><a name="ftn.2" href="#f2" class="tr_ftn">8</a></sup>                   
            <para>text</para>               
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="tr_footnote">
         <div class="footnote"><sup><a name="ftn.3" href="#f3" class="tr_ftn">9</a></sup>                   
            <para>text</para>               
         </div>
      </div>-------------------------<?pb label=''?>
      <div class="tr_footnote">
         <div class="footnote"><sup><a name="ftn.4" href="#f4" class="tr_ftn">20</a></sup>                  
            <para>text</para>               
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="tr_footnote">
         <div class="footnote"><sup><a name="ftn.5" href="#f5" class="tr_ftn">21</a></sup>                  
            <para>text</para>               
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="tr_footnote">
         <div class="footnote"><sup><a name="ftn.6" href="#f6" class="tr_ftn">22</a></sup>                  
            <para>text</para>               
         </div>
      </div>-------------------------<?pb label=''?>
      <div class="tr_footnote">
         <div class="footnote"><sup><a name="ftn.7" href="#f7" class="tr_ftn">23</a></sup>                  
            <para>text</para>               
         </div>
      </div>
   </section>
</hmtl>
```

The condition is this way. there is a `footnote` and `following` to it there are processing instructions, they are of 2 types.  `<?xpp MAIN;2;0;0;0;45;0;0?>` and   `<?xpp foot;art10_ft7;suppress?>`. And here my query is I need to match the `following processing instruction` `containing` `MAIN`, and there should be no other `footnote` between the `current footnote` and the `processing instruction`, and if the condition is matched, I need to draw a line.

I'm using the following xpath to match the condition. But this is not working as expected.

```
<xsl:if test="following::processing-instruction('xpp')/text()[contains(.,'MAIN')][1][preceding::footnote[1]/@label=./@label]">
            <xsl:text>-------------------------</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
```

please let me know how can I do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following expression in your `test` (formatted for readability) * :

```
following-sibling::processing-instruction('xpp')
    [contains(.,'MAIN')]
    [1]
    [preceding-sibling::footnote[1]/@label=current()/@label]
```

You can use more specific axis `following-sibling` here since all elements that matter are at the same level within the same parent element. Then, there is an error is `./@label` at the end of the original `test` expression. The context there is `processing-instruction('xpp')/text()`, which doesn't have such `label` attribute. You need to use `current()` to switch context to currently matched `footnote` :

```
<!--Here I need the change-->
<xsl:if test="following-sibling::processing-instruction('xpp')[contains(.,'MAIN')][1][preceding-sibling::footnote[1]/@label=current()/@label]">
    <xsl:text>-------------------------</xsl:text>
</xsl:if>
```

Testing codes : http://xsltransform.net/pPzifpU

*) you might also be able to compare the element directly in the last predicate, something like : 
`[preceding-sibling::footnote[1]=current()]`

Comment: Hey This worked awesome, but can you please let me know where am i going wrong in my original post.

Comment: @user3872094 Didn't I mention about *"`./@label` at the end of your original `test` expression"* :)